Does $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \exp{\left(\frac{-n^\epsilon}{2\log_2n}\right)}$ converge?
I'm working through the proof for the longest run of heads in a Bernoulli process and I'm having some trouble with the infinite series in the title.
Let $n$ be the total number of tosses in the Bernoulli Process, let $L_n$ be the longest run of consecutive heads observed across $n$ Bernoulli trials, and fix $\epsilon > 0$. The standard proof of the longest run of heads takes $P(L_n < (1+\epsilon)\log_2n) \leq \exp{\left(\frac{-n^{\epsilon}}{2\log_2n}\right)}$ and uses the Borel-Cantelli lemma and the fact that
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \exp{\left(\frac{-n^\epsilon}{2\log_2n}\right)}< \infty$$
to show that the events $A_n = \{L_n < (1+\epsilon)\log_2n\}$ occur only finitely often.
Every reference I have seen simply states that this series converges and moves on. I'm having trouble seeing how exactly it converges, especially when the $n=1$ term is undefined. Can someone please help clarify?
See page 83 of Dembo's Lecture Notes for reference.

The issue for $n=1$ is easily solved, it suffices start from $n=2$.
To prove convergence note that eventually
$$\frac{n^\epsilon}{2\log_2n}\ge n^{\epsilon/2}\implies \frac1{e^{\left(\frac{n^\epsilon}{2\log_2n}\right)}}\le \frac1{e^{n^{\epsilon/2}}}$$
and the series converges by comparison test.

Thanks for this. Why can we just ignore the $n=1$ term?

@Kob The convergence for a series is determined by the tail, so we can start from any value.

@Kob This is similar to limits, when $n \to \infty$ we are not interested what the expression is for any $n$ we are interested to understand its behaviour for $n$ large.

@Kob The series is indeed a limit!

@user $1/\log_2 n =1/0$ for $n=1$, so the sum should start at $n=2$.

@Gary Yes I’ve already indicated that in the first sentence. Isn’t it clear enough? Thanks

@user Sorry, I meant to address Kob. My mistake.

@Gary Ah ok! You’re welcome, Bye!

@Gary Also note that Kob is aware about that, indeed it was a part of their question.
